# keras lstm time series data

Tags: python, time, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a lstm model with data measured once a day over time at different moments of the day.

For example, let's say the last input of my data set has been measured on May 16, 2018. My data is like this:

```
        Velocity        Time 
0        56.122         3600
1        56.114         3601
...      ...            ...
3599     75.043         7199
```

The time is in seconds. From 3600 to 7199 means from 1:00 am to 2:00 am.

Let's say the input before has been measured the day before (May 15) from 00:00 to 00:15.

```
        Velocity        Time 
0        6.232           0
1        6.197           1
...      ...             ...
899      5.507           899
```

The problem is I don't know how to deal with the 'Time' feature when I am creating my LSTM model.

At the moment, I have padded my data so that they all have the same shape. For example, for the input of May 15, I have now

```
        Velocity        Time 
0        6.232           0
1        6.197           1
...      ...             ...
899      5.507           899
900      -1              -1
...      ...             ...
3599     -1              -1
```

I assumed in the example that 1 hour was the maximum time length of the inputs.

Do I need to transform the time into a categorical data ? Because I normalized my data (not seen here) with sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler (I did it before the padding). If not, do I need to scale the time ?

I have 11200 inputs. Each input (X_train) has a shape of (3600, 2). There is one output for each input (it's a boolean True or False).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to transform into categorical data. Normalising is a good starting point but having said that if you want you can make the time discrete by rounding it to the nearest hour for example. This way you can categorise it, this of course will change the information the network gets.

Another approach could be to take the differences between events in seconds and normalise that. This way the data wouldn't have bias towards constantly increasing time input.

Comment: Thank you. No I do not want to change the information of my data. Yes I would like to normalize it. I did not understand your last paragraph. I have also another question, when working with time series data, is it useful to keep the time frame ? The main issue I got is that the time frame for each input is not the same (for example, over 5 min, or 10 min). After padding, the size of the input become the same but now I wondering if the time matters ?(I am still a beginner with nn). Can I train my dataframe without it ?

Comment: By differences I mean instead of having 3600 and 3601 you have 0 1 indicating the amount of time passed since the last event. Keeping time is important if it is not uniform, ie if you not sample at equal timeframes. The padding should be masked as it shouldn't affect prediction.

Comment: Thank you again. I understand better. Yes I have planned to add a Mask layer.